# Magento: use tier_price instead of price

Tags: magento

How can I show and use the *Tier Price* of the **"Customer Group"** to which the current user belongs?

I'm using `Magento ver. 1.4.1.1`

Comment: Not sure what you mean but the tier price can be only applied to product and not customer group.

Comment: @Dick Laurent: that's not correct. Tier prices can be applied per product AND customergroup. See the "Customer Group" drop-down at `Catalog -> Manage Products -> Product -> Prices -> Tier Price`.

Comment: Of course, I konw that, but when we fix a "Tier price" for a product, we can choose to apply it for a customer group or another, and I want to use the price of the corresponding user by considering that the Qty is always 1 and the tier prices are different from a customer group to another...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$oProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);    
$aTierPrice = $oProduct->getTierPrice();
```

to get the proper tier price(s) of a product.

If you define *distinct* tier prices for a product, e.g.

- price of x for customer group 'NOT_LOGGED_IN'
- price of y for customer group 'General'

`getTierPrice()` will only return the matching tier price.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jürgen Thelen, I'm trying to use different prices for each customer group, my problem is now when the tier prices are higher that the normal price, they are not displayed in this case. Do you know what have I to modify to show them ? Thanks for you help.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the template code used to display your products. Just one clue: in case your template is calling standard `getPriceHtml()`, check the 2nd param of the call. If it's `true`, standard Magento will display minimal price. Maybe switching it to `false` will help then.

Comment: I'm using the default template, I've tried to change true to false but the tier prices are not displayed (when they are higher than the normal price).